# Java method place holder in parent to use in children

Tags: java, methods, placeholder

I Need a help to create a java method, i need to create a method in parent without any return and use the same method in children with different criteria. I know there is a way to do it but i can't remember it, any help will be highly appreciated.

```
public abstract class Property // this is the class name, which is parent
```

Is this how i am suppose to do

```
public abstract double calculateTax()
{
    return ;
}
```

Ive to use this same method in children but this is the criteria I've to change

calculateTaxes for CommercialProperty(1st child)

if the square feet is greater than 1500 then if the state code is TX the taxes is market value * .25  else taxes is market value * .20 else if the square feet is less than or equal to 1500 the taxes is market value * .10

calculateTaxes for ResidentialProperty

is .5  * the market value if the floodzone is true taxes is an extra 10%.

I know I'm missing the data but i just wanted to know the concept on how to

Comment: Are you looking to make an [abstract method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)?

Comment: Abstract methods have no bodies.

Comment: @4castle i think thats what it is, i edited my question again hopefully it make more sense, thank you

Comment: explain "different criteria"??

Comment: joho: see my answer - your code sample contains simply bad syntax. **abstract** translates to: **no body**!

Answer (score 1):

A simple example on using **abstract** classes, while keeping in mind the *[Open/Closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle)* goes like this:

```
abstract class A {
  protected abstract String getFoo();
  public final bar() {
    System.out.println("The foo: " + getFoo());
  }
}

class B extends A {
  @Override
  protected String getFoo() { return "whatever"; }
}
```

The ideas here:

1. You use *abstract* method declarations to indicate that extending classes **must** "add" behavior for such methods.
2. And just to be precise: a method declared **abstract** does **not** have a body. No statements, no return, nothing!
3. Still you "fixate" behavior that you want to have in your base class ... right there. And you prevent child classes from **changing** that behavior.

In my example, the abstract method is returning a String; just to make the example more meaningful. Of course, abstract methods can have any signature you want them to have. And for the record: when **overriding** methods in subclasses, don't forget to put the @Override annotation in place!

Comment: It might be good to include that abstract methods *have no bodies*. It seems like the OP doesn't understand that concept. Anyways, all around great answer!

Comment: Did so, thanks for the suggestion!